# Windeployqt won't run, "Access is denied."

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to deploy a Qt application, but every time I try to run `windeployqt.exe` I get this error in Windows popup:

> This app can't run on your PC, to find a version for your PC contact the publisher

And, in terminal:

> Access is denied.

Here's my deployment script, running in the VS 2017 Developer CMD. I don't get errors for anything else so I'm pretty sure `qmake` and `nmake` are working correctly.

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\...\vcvars64.bat"
call C:\Qt\5.13.1\msvc2017_64\bin\qtenv2.bat
C:\Qt\5.13.1\msvc2017_64\bin\qmake.exe CONFIG+=release [path to .pro]
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\...\nmake.exe" [path to Makefile.Release]
copy [path to my qt app executable] [output folder]
cd [output folder]
windeployqt.exe
```

`windeployqt.exe` is in my `PATH` but it still won't run. This is my first time deploying a Qt app and I can't find any documentation that specifies that I need to do anything else before trying to run `windeployqt.exe`. I have also checked relevant folder permissions. The executable for my application is 64-bit, and I'm using the `MSVC2017` compiler. If any additional information is required please let me know.

Comment: Try to run your script as Administrator?

Comment: @Ayxan Running as administrator still produces the same error.

Comment: What is your output folder? Did you try to build and run this in another drive?

Comment: @Azeem The output folder is a folder on my desktop, but I have tried other locations as well as a different drive, still nothing. I do have a different computer I could try it on but I really need this to work on this PC.

Comment: @jkofskie: Did you try to manually go into the binaries folder and then run `winqtdeploy.exe` there? And, is there only one executable in that folder where you're running this? Is your Qt 32- or 64-bit? And, from the script I believe that you're building a 64-bit version so you're Qt version is also 64-bit, right? Kindly update this information in your question as well.

Comment: @Azeem Got it working. Yes, the app is 64-bit. However, the about section in Qt only shows the version of Visual C++, which is 32-bit, obviously. I decided to reinstall Qt anyway, and that solved it. Thank you for your help. I don't know exactly what the problem was, but I'm glad it works now. What would be the proper way to check if Qt is 32-bit or 64-bit? I want to see if that was the problem so I can accurately answer my question.

Comment: @jkofskie: Awesome! Actually, I suspected due to the popup error that the `winqtdeploy.exe` was a 32-bit app and it tried to get info from a 64-bit binary that's why I asked about the Qt build. You can check by using a 32-bit executable to confirm this. BTW, I'm glad it's solved. Cheers. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A reinstall of Qt solved this problem. As Azeem pointed out, a 32-bit version of `windeployqt` was trying to work with a 64-bit binary.

Answer (score 7):

If you've ended up here because you upgraded to Qt 6.5, and now you're getting `Access Denied` in the console, you can work around this by adding `--no-translations` to the `windeployqt` command line. It is a bug that's [already been fixed](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-112204).